Jenkins securityrealm
I have the github oauth client and secret stored in GCP secret manager and using secret manager plugin the credentials are loaded into Jenkins credentials
How can I use these credentials in securityRealm in jenkins, is it because I am trying to create a credentials also at the same time, how can I get around this??
I tried to use the following code
securityrealm: |-
  jenkins:
    securityRealm:
        github:
          clientID: "${github_clientid}"
          clientSecret: "${github_clientid}"
          githubApiUri: "https://api.github.com"
          githubWebUri: "https://github.com"
          oauthScopes: "read:org,user:email,repo"

But I am getting following error
WARNING i.j.p.c.SecretSourceResolver$UnresolvedLookup#lookup: Configuration import: Found unresolved variable 'git_oauth_clientId'. Will default to empty string
2024-10-06 22:15:24.282+0000 [id=29]    WARNING i.j.p.c.SecretSourceResolver$UnresolvedLookup#lookup: Configuration import: Found unresolved variable 'git_oauth_clientsecret'. Will default to empty string
2024-10-06 22:15:24.304+0000 [id=29]    WARNING i.j.p.casc.BaseConfigurator#createAttribute: Can't handle class javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.GlobalJobDslSecurityConfiguration#metaClass: type is abstract but not Describable.

